# Panel.repaint(); messes up layout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

JPanel Initiation

```
    p = new JPanel() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            if(errors == 1)
                g.drawOval(215, 50, 75, 75);
            else if(errors == 2)
                g.drawOval(200,200,200,200);
        }
    };
```

Method that calls `repaint`

```
static void drawHead() {
    System.out.println("Head");
    errors = 1;
    p.removeAll();
    p.revalidate();
    p.repaint();
}
```

Before `repaint` my frame looks like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8F0V.png

And afterwards it looks like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFwr0.png

I'm thinking there is an error in my `drawHead()` method but I cannot seem to resolve the issue. Does anyone know what is going on? My desired outcome would be the first image, but with a `head` drawn in.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) For many components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { if(errors == 1)..` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); if(errors == 1)..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've broken the paint chain by failing to call `super.paintComponent` first before you performed any custom painting

`Graphics` is shared resource, every component painted in a during a paint cycle will share the same `Graphics` context, this means that whatever was previously painted to the `Graphics` context will remain unless you clear it.

One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting by filling it with the background color of the component

Comment: That fixes it. Thanks! Who knew it could be that simple.

Comment: I'd also consider using a `switch` statement instead of an `if` statement and reverse the order in which the values are checked, this would allow you to keep count of the number of errors but reduce the amount of duplicated code you would need to produce in order to get the `if` statement to work